# Cannot install SDK for API 26. Error: The following packages are not available

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Package id platforms;android-26:
[image: - Package id platforms;android-26]

SDK doesn't show packages to download.

> Error: The following packages are not available: - Package id platforms;android-26

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall android studio and delete full SDK of android again reinstall in your PC may be it will work if it will not work then check JDK it has properly in your PC or not.